# Structure for Categories, subcategories and Products

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have a table "Category" and another "Subcategory". Then I have "Products" table.

Some of these products will be related directly to the "Subcategroy" table, but some of them will be related **directly** to "Category". What should be the tables structure in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Use Association Mapping

This chapter explains mapping associations between objects.

Instead of working with foreign keys in your code, you will always work with references to objects instead and Doctrine will convert those references to foreign keys internally.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: thanks, but Im already working with Association Mapping. I was wondering about the relation between the tables, finally I'm using a one to many self-referencing relation to represent categories and subcategories: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing